# Rspec / Capybara clicking on button that was generated using javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a generated a button with javascript:

```
<script>
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Do Something";

  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  body.appendChild(button);    
</script>
```

but can't seem to be able to find that button using Capybara
e.g:

```
find_button 'Do Something' or click_button 'Do Something'
```

produces `Unable to find button "Do Something"`

has anyone come across anything like this before?

Comment: Are you using a javascript driver like selenium? Unless you have your JS enabled, just capybara and rspec won't be able to handle this.

Comment: James Milani is probably correct about the issue here - see  https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#selecting-the-driver . If you are actually using a JS capable driver then look at the output of `page.html` and see what the HTML actually looks like

Comment: I was able to solve it by adding webkit driver using link from James and enabling js: true for my specific scenario. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added to Gemfile and bundle install:

```
gem 'capybara-webkit'
```

Add to rails_helper:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

Enabled js on  specific rspec scenario
e.g:

```
scenario "dynamic button generated", js: true do
 ...
end
```